# How to compile and migrate to DPC++

Tags: c++, intel, intel-oneapi, dpc++

I have cloned a github repository which has some C++ and OpenCL project to my devcloud account.
Is there a way to migrate these opencl files to DPC++?
I want to work with jupyter notebook will it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can migrate OpenCL applications to DPC++ because DPC++ includes SYCL, which is a higher-level abstraction layer that builds on OpenCL, when comparing DPC++ and OpenCL, most fundamental concepts are the same with an easy mapping of equivalent constructs between OpenCL and DPC++.

Here is the article which gives more details regarding the same
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/migrating-opencl-designs-to-dpcpp.html

You can use the Intel compilers to run applications,
and the Jupyter notebook can also be used to migrate from OpenCL to DPC++.